# OpengGL glDrawBuffers() in Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl

is the OpenGL function glDrawBuffers(GLsizei n, const GLenum *bufs) available in Qt?
I'm trying to pass multiple render targets to my fragment shader, QtCreator says the function is not declared in this scope. The idea is to have a frame buffer object with two colorbuffers, and draw with the fragment shader to those two buffers.

FIXED:
Just had to add #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1 to the offending file :(

Comment: If you've got fragment shaders and such working, then you must have some kind of extension loading code. What GL version are you getting when you create your context?

Comment: @Nicol: glGetString(GL_VERSION) gives me "3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.40". The GL context was set using makeCurrent() from QGLWidget. If I remove the FBO, the shaders work perfectly (i.e. using the default window color buffer)

Comment: What are you using to load your OpenGL functions?

Comment: My widget class inherits QGLWidget, and now QGLFunctions (for the Framebufferfunctions). Apart from that I just import from QtOpenGL.h
All function for binding, linking, etc. shaders, and other gl functions worked fine right out of the box, the only problem is glDrawBuffers().

Answer (score 1):

Qt offers only rudimentary access to OpenGL functions. Loading shaders and textures are amongst them. Render targets are not. Just use a proper extension loader library like GLEW. GLEW will nicely coexist with Qt's functionality.

Derive from QGLWidget and override `glInit` to call `glewInit` after calling `initializeGL`

Comment: Thanks, after hours of trying I found I was making a very stupid mistake: I forgot the #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1 so that the interface to the extensions become visible to nVidia, all is solved now, without the need of GLEW, thanks a lot anyways

Answer (score 0):

We just spent some time fixing this. We are running Qt 5.2.1 on **OSX 10.8** and **Ubuntu 14.04** (sorry no **WINDOWS** experience) and created an **OpenGL3.2** context using QGLFormat.

In **OSX** there is no problem as all OpenGL3.2 functions (to set uniforms, draw buffers, etc..) are defined in:

```
#include "OpenGL/gl3.h" ///< already included by Qt.. so nothing to do
```

On **Linux** on the other hand, we have to include **BOTH** of these:

```
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glext.h" ///< not included by Qt!!! manually include it
```

We also *attempted* to have our QGLWidget class inherit from **QGLFunctions_3_2_Core** (this class defines its own copy of glDrawBuffer etc...), but this wasn't useful and simply resulted in a *segfault*:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0000000000407068 
in glGetUniformLocation (this=0xbc5820, name=0x407cd0 "view_projection", program=1) 
at /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qopenglfunctions_3_2_core.h:1075 1075     
return d_2_0_Core->GetUniformLocation(program, name);
```

We also investigated the "#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1" above, but this was only useful when we were using *glcorearb.h* (you can download this header online).

Comment: Minor correction: On OS X, the OpenGL 3.2 functions are defined in `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`. Note the `gl3.h` instead of `gl.h`.